# Deactivate view moveUp when showing keyboard on iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8

In my application, I have a signing up form, with some textFields (Email, password etc ...), when I begin typing somewhere in these textFields (The keyboard is shown), my View moves Up, and I'm not able to see what's being typed in my text field.

This problem occurs only with iOS8.

If some one knows how to block this os feature, i'll be thankful.

Regards.

Comment: To make sure your keyboard doesn't block the view I use IQKeyboardManager.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this library, it's really awesome, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem :/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you be more precise ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for managing issues related to Keyboard appearance and disappearance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
} 

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

#pragma mark - Keyboard Delegate
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    //to overcome the bug with keyboard height for os7 and earlier
    if (![UIDeviceHardware isOS8Device]) {
        CGRect kbRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
        kbRect = [self.view convertRect:kbRect fromView:nil];
        kbSize = kbRect.size;
    }

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    _scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

You can pick `activeField` from `UITextfield Delegate`.

Answer (score 0):

This will be useful to you..

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if (textField == (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:TEXTFIELD_MOBILE_TAG])
    {
        CGRect selfframe = CGRectMake([self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_PARENT_TAG].frame.origin.x, [self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_PARENT_TAG].frame.origin.y - 80, [self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_PARENT_TAG].frame.size.width, [self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_PARENT_TAG].frame.size.height);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{ [self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_PARENT_TAG].frame = selfframe;}];
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if (textField == (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:TEXTFIELD_MOBILE_TAG])
    {
        CGRect selfframe = CGRectMake([self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_PARENT_TAG].frame.origin.x, [self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_PARENT_TAG].frame.origin.y + 80, [self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_PARENT_TAG].frame.size.width, [self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_PARENT_TAG].frame.size.height);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{ [self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_PARENT_TAG].frame = selfframe;}];
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }

}
```